# Difference between "introduction to" and "introduction of"

Tags: grammar, differences

What exactly is the difference between "introduction to" and "introduction of"?

For example: should it be "Introduction to the problem" or "Introduction of the problem"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two different meanings here:

> (1) the action of introducing something
>   *issues arising from the introduction of new technology*

> (2) a thing preliminary to something else, especially an explanatory section at the beginning of a book, report, or speech
>   *a good general introduction to the subject is A Social History of England*

From [oxforddictionaries.com](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_gb0418840#m_en_gb0418840).

I suspect you want meaning (2):

> *The first paragraph provides an introduction to the problem.*

Answer (score 5):

It's an *introduction of a problem to the people*, therefore:

> Let me introduce this problem to our employees.
>   An introduction of this problem was made to our employees.

But, you can also say

> I've been introduced to the problem.
>   Our employees were introduced to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of meaning and usage.

Both of "introduction of" and "introduction to" are grammatical and have the same meaning in the following case:

> Do you mind giving us an introduction of the problem?
>
> Do you mind giving us an introduction to the problem?

But, they will have different meanings in the case below:

> Your introduction to the problem will last 5 minutes. ("You" are going to be introduced)
>
> Your introduction of the problem will last 5 minutes. (The meaning here is ambiguous: 1) "You" are going to be introduced or 2) "You" are the one who introduced the problem to others)

Comment: I have to disagree: I believe ``your introduction of the problem`` doesn't mean that you are going to be introduced to the problem, it only means the latter: that you are going to be introducing the problem to others. But I will not down-vote your answer unless someone else agrees with me by up-voting this comment.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of usage and meaning, some examples:

> "Our students are learning English faster since the introduction of new classroom methods."

- Here, "Introduction of" has more to
  do with ideas, techniques and
  articles.

> "With the introduction of penicillin, pneumonia was no longer as life-threatening as before."

- Here, "Introduction of" refers to
  bringing something into a place or
  situation.

> "Can you give me an introduction to the president of the company?"

- "Introduction to" is more commonly
  used in referring to presenting
  someone to another person.

> "Since my introduction to the use of the DVD player, I watch more movies than before."

- "introduction to" has to do with a
  meeting, either between people, or
  between a person or person, and an
  idea, situation, thing, etc.

So, for your case, "introduction of the problem" should be correct, according to first one.

Comment: It would be nice if you could leave a comment on why down-vote!